# How to type a hashtable whose keys can only be members of an enum?

Tags: enums, hashtable

In Typescript I can add a type for a hashtable `foo` whose keys are members of an enum `Flag` with `foo: { [key in Flag]: any}`. However, this requires that foo contains a key-value pair for every member of the `Flag` enum. What if I just want it to be partial - to say that the keys in foo can only be members of `Flag`, but I'm not expecting every member of `Flag`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a question mark to mark the keys as optional:

`foo: { [key in Flag]?: any}`